# Concurrently write multiple csv files from one, splitting on a partition column in Golang

Tags: csv, go, concurrency, channel

My objective is to read one or multiple csv files that share a common format, and write to separate files based on a partition column in the csv data. Please allow that the last column is the partition, that data is un-sorted, and a given partition can be found in multiple files. Example of one file:

```
fsdio,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1sdf9,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
22df9,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
1d243,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
```

*If this approach smells like the dreaded XY Problem, I'm happy to adjust.*

What I've tried so far:

- Read in the data set and iterate over each line
- If the partition has
  been seen, spin off a new worker routine (this will contain a file/csv
  writer). Send the line into a `chan []string`.
- As each worker is a file writer, it should only receive lines for exactly one partition over it's input channel.

This obviously doesn't work (yet),  as I'm not aware of how to send a line to the correct worker based on the partition value seen on a given line.

I've given each worker an `id string` for each partition value, but am not aware how to select that worker to send to, if I should be creating a separate `chan []string` for each worker and send to that channel with a `select`, or if perhaps a struct should hold each worker with some sort of pool and routing functionality.

TLDR; I'm lost as to how to conditionally send data to a given go routine or channel based on some categorical `string` value, where the number of unique's can be arbitrary, but likely does not exceed 24 unique partition values.

*I will caveat by stating I've noticed questions like this do get down-voted, so if you feel this is counter-constructive or incomplete enough to down-vote, please comment with why so I can avoid repeating the offense.*

Thanks for any help in advance!

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YhT9V4yLl-)

Snippet:

```
  package main

    import (
        "encoding/csv"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "strings"
        "time"
    )

    func main() {

        // CSV
        r := csv.NewReader(csvFile1)
        lines, err := r.ReadAll()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error reading all lines: %v", err)
        }

        // CHANNELS
        lineChan := make(chan []string)

        // TRACKER
        var seenPartitions []string

        for _, line := range lines {

            hour := line[6]
            if !stringInSlice(hour, seenPartitions) {
                seenPartitions = append(seenPartitions, hour)
                go worker(hour, lineChan)
            }
            // How to send to the correct worker/channel? 
            lineChan <- line

        }
        close(lineChan)
    }

    func worker(id string, lineChan <-chan []string) {
        for j := range lineChan {
            fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", j)
            // Write to a new file here and wait for input over the channel
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        }
    }

    func stringInSlice(str string, list []string) bool {
        for _, v := range list {
            if v == str {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    // DUMMY
var csvFile1 = strings.NewReader(`
12fy3,abc,def,2017,11,06,04 
fsdio,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
11213,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
1sdf9,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
2123r,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
1v2t3,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1r2r3,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
g1253,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
d1e23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
a1d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
12jj3,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
t1r23,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
22123,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
14d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
1d243,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1da23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
a1523,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
12453,abc,def,2017,11,06,04`)
```

Comment: Create a `map[string](chan []string)`. Then given a partition key you can send the row to a corresponding channel.

Comment: Agree w/@zerkms. Or for more flexibility while keeping things simple, make each worker an instance of a `struct` type that holds its ID, a channel for sending rows, a quit channel to tell it when to stop/flush/close, and anything else it needs, and then hold a `map[string]worker` and use that to send the correct line to the correct worker.

Comment: Thanks so much guys!
I've created these suggested constructs,  but am not quite sure:
- how to prevent deadlock
- how to append to the map[string]worker as suggested to keep track (I called this workerPool)
- still, how to choose among the workers I've already created

Current progress here:
https://play.golang.org/p/j56r_QvSJs

Comment: @gpanda channels aren't well suited to act as an unbound totally ordered queues. Instead, you may create a structure that holds a lock (a mutex) and internally is implemented as a slice. Then on every `push` you append an element to the slice, and on every `pop` you take one from the head.

Comment: Point well taken, @zerkms.
Still, with this approach I'm so close! Just get deadlock after all routines finish. 
https://play.golang.org/p/8T1swVHlgT
Will work on this and report back after I've tried your mux solution.

Comment: Hi @zerkms, Adrian. After reading up, I successfully implemented this using sync.Mutex. My solution is here: https://play.golang.org/p/7vFroFQLxS
If it's proper form here, I'll edit my question with the answer as I feel presumptuous answering my own question because you both were so helpful and I couldn't have done it without your patience :)
I hope you see some other improvement like the _, ok syntax.
For those like me struggling with this, consider:
"A common Go newbie mistake is to over-use channels...  Don’t be afraid to use a Mutex if that fits your problem best..."

Happy coding :)

Comment: @gpanda I think it's not thread safe: `workerPool` access must be synchronised as well, since you read-write to it concurrently. Besides that, when you make it concurrency-safe you would find out that nothing in your implementation guarantees order: so lines might be scheduled to be processed in an arbitrary order.

Comment: @zerkms I'm ok with lines being processed in arbitrary order as the data is coming out of order, as long as a single worker is guaranteed to only receive exactly one unique partition. Can you please add some detail as to why workerPool as implemented is unsafe? I'm really just using it to keep track of whether I've created a worker for the partition from the current line or not.

Comment: `workerPool[hour] = w` - here is a modification, `workerPool[hour].Work(l)` here is read from `workerPool`. If a shared piece of data is accessed concurrently and if at least one of those accesses is modification - the access must be syncrhonised. You may solve it using the `sync.RWMutex`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159019/discussion-between-gpanda-and-zerkms).

Comment: @zerkms moved to chat per mod request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous version no go concurrent magic first (see concurrent version below).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    // CSV
    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile1)
    partitions := make(map[string][][]string)

    for {
        rec, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil

                save_partitions(partitions)

                return
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        process(rec, partitions)
    }

}

// prints only
func save_partitions(partitions map[string][][]string) {
    for part, recs := range partitions {
        fmt.Println(part)
        for _, rec := range recs {
            fmt.Println(rec)
        }
    }
}

// this can also write/append directly to a file
func process(rec []string, partitions map[string][][]string) {
    l := len(rec)
    part := rec[l-1]
    if p, ok := partitions[part]; ok {
        partitions[part] = append(p, rec)
    } else {
        partitions[part] = [][]string{rec}
    }
}

// DUMMY
var csvFile1 = strings.NewReader(`
fsdio,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1sdf9,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1d243,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1v2t3,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
a1523,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1r2r3,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
11213,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
g1253,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
d1e23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
a1d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
12jj3,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
t1r23,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
2123r,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
22123,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
14d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
1da23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
12fy3,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
12453,abc,def,2017,11,06,04`)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/--iqZGzxCF

And the concurrent version:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var (
    // list of channels to communicate with workers
    // workers accessed synchronousely no mutex required
    workers = make(map[string]chan []string)

    // wg is to make sure all workers done before exiting main
    wg = sync.WaitGroup{}

    // mu used only for sequential printing, not relevant for program logic
    mu = sync.Mutex{}
)

func main() {

    // wait for all workers to finish up before exit
    defer wg.Wait()

    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile1)

    for {
        rec, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                savePartitions()
                return
            }
            log.Fatal(err) // sorry for the panic
        }
        process(rec)
    }

}

func process(rec []string) {
    l := len(rec)
    part := rec[l-1]

    if c, ok := workers[part]; ok {
        // send rec to worker
        c <- rec
    } else {
        // if no worker for the partition

        // make a chan
        nc := make(chan []string)
        workers[part] = nc

        // start worker with this chan
        go worker(nc)

        // send rec to worker via chan
        nc <- rec
    }
}

func worker(c chan []string) {

    // wg.Done signals to main worker completion
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    part := [][]string{}
    for {
        // wait for a rec or close(chan)
        rec, ok := <-c
        if ok {
            // save the rec
            // instead of accumulation in memory
            // this can be saved to file directly
            part = append(part, rec)
        } else {
            // channel closed on EOF

            // dump partition
            // locks ensures sequential printing
            // not a required for independent files
            mu.Lock()
            for _, p := range part {
                fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
            }
            mu.Unlock()

            return
        }
    }
}

// simply signals to workers to stop
func savePartitions() {
    for _, c := range workers {
        // signal to all workers to exit
        close(c)
    }
}

// DUMMY
var csvFile1 = strings.NewReader(`
fsdio,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1sdf9,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1d243,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1v2t3,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
a1523,abc,def,2017,11,06,01
1r2r3,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
11213,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
g1253,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
d1e23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
a1d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,02
12jj3,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
t1r23,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
2123r,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
22123,abc,def,2017,11,06,03
14d23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
1da23,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
12fy3,abc,def,2017,11,06,04
12453,abc,def,2017,11,06,04`)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oBTPosy0yT

Have fun!

Comment: I will absolutely have a look at how this works for my use case and report back with any questions. Thanks!

Comment: Both solutions are great, but the second is especially elegant. I especially appreciate the , ok syntax for use of closing the chan in worker(), as well as the explanatory comments. I'm curious about the comment about how the Lock() is not required for independent files. I think this is where I will adapt to write to a separate csv for each partition - are you sure a lock wouldn't be required here for writing each partition to a file?

Comment: @gpanda yes I'm pretty sure you don't need to Lock for that. It is only required because when printing we have one single shared resource std out where we print to. Try commenting out the `mu.Lock and mu.Unlock`. Nothing bad will happen except order of lines will be random. With this lock each worker is saying "Look everyone shut-up while up speaking". When you have one file per worker you are not sharing anything so you can think of `part := [][]string{}` as your file. And we are not locking it for appending to it.